Include only a subdir with Timeshift backup
With Timeshift, is there a way to include only a sub-directory?
Example:
Exclude /var but include /var/lib/libvirt/images
I've tried some combinations but doesn't works!
There is an example:


If you are using the rsync version of timeshift, you need to explicitly have an include for each of the sub-directories leading to the final wanted path. The exclude must follow these includes. I don't know if the gui allows it, but you would need:
+ /var
+ /var/lib
+ /var/lib/libvirt
+ /var/lib/libvirt/images
+ /var/lib/libvirt/images/***
- /var/**

This can be reduced to
+ /var/lib
+ /var/lib/libvirt
+ /var/lib/libvirt/images/***
- /var/**

assuming /var is included by default, and since /var/lib/libvirt/images
will be matched by the *** in /var/lib/libvirt/images/***. The last
line must not be - /var/*** as this would exclude /var.
